# How to override password validation in FOSUserBundle

Tags: validation, symfony, passwords, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle in my Symfony2 project. I can't find any sensible explanation how to override form fields validation. I need to set password field validation to at least 7 characters, at least one small letter, at least one capital letter and at least one digit. None of solutions I've found alreade seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16):

Use a standard `Regex` constraint with the following pattern `/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{7,}/`

```
class User extends FOSUser
{

    /**
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *  pattern="/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{7,}/",
     *  message="Password must be seven or more characters long and contain at least one digit, one upper- and one lowercase character."
     * )
     */
    protected $plainPassword;

}
```

Comment: will this add a new constraint ? or erase and add ?

Answer (score 1):

you shoud create a custom constraint class  like [described in documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#creating-the-validator-itself)

1. Add your regex expression inside isValid method
2. Add your custom error messages
3. add your constraint class to your entity class with validation.yml (or with annotations if you prefer)

that should fit your needs